# Web browser from console CentOS

Tags: centos, console, browser

Is it possible to run any graphical browser (not lynx) from the console on CentOS 1708 without any installed GUI on it? I need to access the web interface of the device, but won't install a GUI on it.

Comment: You can use [SDL based vnc client](https://github.com/vidarh/sdlvnc) and a vnc server which is running firefox/chromium.

Comment: Do you require a headless browser? Both Chrome and Firefox support a headless mode now in the same way PhantomJS works.

Comment: Not a headless. I require answer for a question - can be firefox, chrome or similar run without GUI.We have monitor and keyboard and mouse on server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is like "How to fetch HTML web page content from bash and display on screen using shell utilities?"

Fedora / RHEL / CentOS Linux install curl, wget, lynx, and w3m

Open a terminal and and then type:

```
$ sudo yum install curl wget lynx w3m

wget -O - https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/401068/web-browser-from-console-centos
```

To read the full article [Bash: Display Web Page Content In Terminal](https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/unix-linux-get-the-contents-of-a-webpage-in-a-terminal/)

Comment: Thank you for reply, but not exactly. What are you talking about - was my target. But lately it transformed in some kind of principal question and to show my boss that he is wrong. He told me, its possible to run graphical browser (like firefox or chrome) from shell without GUI, like 'yum install firefox' and then just root@localhost$ firefox, and it should open a window of firefox. Ive told him no way without GUI. So it was my general question here - is it possible or not without gui. I know about links, but that was not what i'm questioning about. Thank you.

Comment: Oh I see, and I'm happy to help. BTW, so your question is something like this? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/9107/how-can-i-run-firefox-on-linux-headlessly-i-e-without-requiring-libgtk-x11-2-0  which is impossible?

Comment: Yes, my question was the same.

Answer (score 10):

There are two common browsers that I've seen:

- [lynx](http://lynx.invisible-island.net/current/index.html)
- [links](http://links.twibright.com/)

There are many less common ones, and as @gad3r pointed out some newer ones.  Why not lynx?  Do you have a special purpose in mind?

Comment: Special purpose - to get access on the web interface to login on device. I cant do it with lyns i dunno why. And also my boss says, there is a possibility to run normal browser (like chrome or firefox) without GUI and i says no, there is no way to do so without GUI.

Comment: @AlexandrAnufriev: You probably need a javascript capable browser. Give **links** a try:  [links JS capable](http://links.twibright.com/user_en.html#ap-javascript)

Comment: Do you need JS? you just need to fetch the static HTML content

Comment: And you can even strip the HTML tags just like it shows in this answer: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/42636/how-to-get-text-of-a-page-using-wget-without-html

Comment: It's your second best answer for me :D thank you so much.

Comment: Also `links2` and some versions of `elinks` have graphical and mouse support.  You'll need `gpm` set up as well to use mouse.

Comment: @AlexandrAnufriev there are a lot of headless browsers that would work that are basically chrome and firefox. Chrome recently added a headless mode behind a flag, for example.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`googler`](https://github.com/jarun/googler):

> Google Search, Google Site Search, Google News from the terminal

Installation :

```
git clone https://github.com/jarun/googler.git
cd googler
sudo make install
```

To use `googler` you need python3 , just install it and launch `googler` from python3 environment without changing  the default python.

```
sudo yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm
sudo yum -y install python36u
```

**Update**

`ddgr` tool is available [here](https://github.com/jarun/ddgr) or [here](https://github.com/jarun/ddgr/releases/tag/v1.1) (rpm):

> `ddgr` is a cmdline utility to search DuckDuckGo from the terminal.

```
git clone https://github.com/jarun/ddgr.git
cd ddgr/
sudo make install
```

see `ddgr -h` for help.

Answer (score 2):

You said in a comment:

> And also my boss says, there is a possibility to run normal browser (like chrome or firefox) without GUI and i says no, there is no way to do so without GUI.

That isn’t true. Both Chrome and Firefox support headless modes. Similar to PhantomJS, their use is more geared towards tooling and testing, but that may fit your use case. See:

[Chrome Headless](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/headless/README.md)

Comment: He was talking about firefox or chrome, or similar. He said, that its enough to "yum install firefox" and then "local$ firefox" to start it. Without any additional configurations or expansions, or how is it called properly in linux. Thank you for your answer! So he thought it should works like: 1. Loggoing on server via putty ssh, installing chrome, running chrome. I said - no way. He didn't know abouy any headless mode, or even lynx. He used firefox before on this server, but in the past there was installed gnome! So i told him about that.

Comment: And btw, i dont need headless solution. What i was looking for was described before. Simple question - can be chrome of firefox or similar work only with "yum install..." without expansions like Xs, GUI.

Answer (score 2):

`netsurf` has a graphical framebuffer mode that can be run on a tty. This needs to be specially compiled and it requires framebuffer support.

When it is working, you can use most graphical pages from your tty, the same way as you would use `netsurf` under X11 or similar.